# How to find all DOM nodes with contenteditable true

Tags: javascript, dom

How can you find all DOM nodes with attribute `contenteditable` true, without jQuery?

I think there must be smarter way of doing it rather than getiing all `div` and `p` elements by `document.getElementsByTagName` and furthermore attributes checking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]')`

> [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]'))
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</p>
<p contenteditable="false">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</p>
<div contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</div>
```